# Is the power set ordered by cardinalities well ordered?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

For any non empty set $X$; $A,B \in \mathcal{P}(X)$, the power set, define $A\sim B \iff $ both $A$ and $B$ have same cardinality and let $\tilde{X}$ denote the equivalence classes.

For $\tilde{A}, \tilde{B}\in\tilde{X}$, define $\tilde{A} \preccurlyeq\tilde{B} \iff |\tilde{A}| \leq |\tilde{B}|$  where $|\tilde{A}|$ denotes the cardinality of $\tilde{A}$.

Now, we know that the axiom of choice implies that $\preccurlyeq$ is a total order.  What I wish to know is whether it is a well-order.

Comment: The class of all cardinalities is well-ordered, so any restriction of it is.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Do you have any source on this?  Everything I have read so far dances around the idea but never explicitly states it.  (On a side note, I'm not very well versed with order theory so it may just be that i have not been able to connect the dots.  In any case, any source would be helpful)

Comment: In ZFC each set is in one-to-one correspondence with some ordinal, so map each set to the least such ordinal. Then, each cardinality equivalence class is represented by some ordinal in the range of this map, and the standard ordering of these ordinals matches the cardinality ordering. These ordinals are called the cardinals, or the alephs. This will be in any set theory book. Or start here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number